# C# asp.net SQL over tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Two database tables:
1)Client (ClientID, Name)
2)Purchase (ClientID, Name)

**Situation**:
Login page --> online purchase page
(Session with username)

**Problem**:
How can i make the SQL over different tables?
I want to insert Clientno in Purchase tables when clients make purchase.

Fail SQL: ( The session is okay )

```
string id = Convert.ToString(Session["UserID"]);

string query1 = "insert int Purchase ([Clientno]) values('"+@clientno+"') where [select Clientno where name ='"+id+"')";
```

Comment: insert int, or insert into?

Comment: into  but  it seems not logically work

Comment: You need to share your specific error message etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the results of a select into a table without a `VALUES` clause, so the straight SQL would look something like this (I changed your query from Clientno to ClientID based on your table definitions up top):

```
INSERT INTO Purchase ([ClientID])
SELECT ClientID
   FROM Client
   WHERE Name = @ID
```

You really want to use parameterized queries though, and not build your SQL inline, like you are doing.

I don't know what other fields you might want to be inserting, but this is the general format of that sort of query.

Comment: INSERT INTO Purchase ([ClientID] )  <-----------how to save it into a variable "ClientID"?
SELECT ClientID
   FROM Client
   WHERE Name = @ID

Comment: `DECLARE @ClientID int; SELECT @ClientID = ClientID FROM Client WHERE Name = @ID`

Comment: um  your insert SQL seems a little problem that i cannot function properly

Comment: You're going to need to give more description of the problem than that. I can assure you the syntax is valid - what part is not working for you?